# Is the maintainer of a database a good or bad reviewer in principle?

Tags: peer-review, databases

I have used a large database comprising the equivalent of about 10 studies.
Would the researcher in charge of this database be a good peer reviewer? As an editor, would they be a good selection?

On one hand, they know the database and the field very well, on the other hand, you could make the argument they may be biased in favor of publication because it draws attention to their project and cites the associated papers.

Answer (score 3):

It is impossible to say whether they would be good or not, but it is fine to suggest them. It will be the editor that chooses, in any case. And they are unlikely to be the only reviewer. Don't worry about it. If you think they have the required skill it is fine to suggest. You don't need to make a judgement.

The editor, being human, will use their own judgement. But a reviewer, promoting their own work and giving unwarranted positive reviews will probably be easy for the editor to see.

Comment: Thanks. I tweaked my language a little - I know that, as an author, I can suggest them, there will be multiple anyway, and that the editor will ultimately decide. I mean in principle, would they be rejected because of their connection to the db in the same way a former mentor of an author would be rejected out of hand?

Comment: Only the editor can say

Comment: The maintainer of a database might be in the best position to review your use of the data (like checking that you didn't mix up anything, confused male and female patients in a medical study for example), and useless at judging the scientific content. It would definitely be a worthwhile review. And the best science is useless if your data is wrong.